# Check homeomorphic sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:0\le|x|=|y|\le1\}$, $Y=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|+|y|=1\}$ and $Z=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}=1\}$, be the subspaces of euclidean space in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$,Then

(a) X is homeomorphic to Y and Z

(b) X is hoemomorphic to Y, but not Z

(c) Y is homeomorhic to Z, but not X

(d) Z is homeomorphic to X, but not Y

What I know, to check homeomorphic we can see the shape of the corresponding graph and if they are similar they are homeomorphic. First set i am not getting, Second is a parallelogram and third is a circle..So by Shape I can say Y is not homeomorphic to Z,..But in the solution it is given option C.

Please help me where I am going wrong and tell me what the first set represent.

Comment: In your definition of $X$, did you mean "$|x|-|y|$" instead of "$|x|=|y|$"?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of what "shape" means is different from what whoever told you that "homeomorphic" means "same shape" means to them. You may be better off working with the actual definition of homeomorphism. A homeomorphism is a one-to-one correspondence that is continuous and whose inverse one-to-one correspondence is also continuous.

Draw a picture of that parallelogram (a diamond) and a picture of the circle in the same plane. Can you describe a specific one-to-one correspondence from the diamond to the circle? Chances are that your choice of correspondence will be a homeomorphism. To make this precise through a formula, you may need to think about the process of normalizing a vector, which maps a vector to a corresponding unit vector.

To get a sense of $X$, try plotting all points $(x, y)$ such that $|x| = |y| = 1/2$. There are four of them. Do the same with $3/4$ in place of $1/2$. The process is similar for $|x| = |y| = t$ for any $t$ in the interval $0 < t \leq 1$. For $t = 0$, you'll get only one point: what is it? When you have done all this, you should see what $X$ looks like.

Comment: Actually I am little afraid of the definition of homeomorphic which asks to find function which is  one one and onto and inverse also continuous and one-one, so I thought to go with shape.  Can you tell how can I defined here such function from Y to Z.., I am finding it difficult.

Comment: The pictorial idea is to "push out" every point on the diamond Y along its radial direction, i.e., the direction going outward from the origin and through the diamond point, until you hit the corresponding point on the unit circle Z. For example, the point $(1/2, 1/2)$ would push out to $(\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$. In terms of formulas, this pushing-out process takes a vector like $v = (1/2, 1/2)$ to its normalization $v/\|v\|$, which is a unit vector (viewed as a point in the unit circle). The idea is that the function $f(v) = v/\|v\|$ describes a continuous function $f: Y \to Z$.

Comment: But to refine your sense of what "shape" is supposed to mean: two spaces like $Y$ and $Z$ have the same shape if you can continuously deform $Y$ into $Z$ so that the inversion of this deformation is also continuous. If you think of the diamond $Y$ as made of rubber, then you are radially stretching out the shape $Y$ into the shape $Z$. (Such a thing will not be possible with your $X$.) It takes a lot of practice learning how to convert this intuition into proofs, so if you can, talk a lot with your professor or with those who are more experienced.